# Magento product images not loading in frontend after product import

Tags: magento2

I have recently imported products alongwith product images from Magento 2.3 import tool. After import, these images are showing in Admin panel but not in frontend.

When I see the path in frontend, I find it like this:

https://mywebsite/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/0881516b480c504c1d3d479a585547eb/agst02-natural-study-table-home-office-desk-solid-wood-tulsa-6.png

I tried to figure out the same path but not present, the actual images are present on the path /pub/media/catalog/product directory which I feel is perfect for magento to work but actually no luck.

What I did as remedy is below:

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/media

But none of the solutions is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

The above command should regenerate the images in the required folders.

Comment: this is amazing.

Comment: happy to help :)